# How do I export cell fractured text for Element 3D?

Tags: export

I've seen a handful of tutorials similar to what I am trying to do.  Some are just using cell fracture but don't export it for use in After Effects Element 3D plugin.  Some use the basic fracture tool but it doesn't give me the results I am looking for.

What I've done so far is add text, rotate and extrude.  Then I convert the text to a mesh and apply cell fracture to it.  I then export it with write normals and triangulate faces both checked in addition to the default settings.  At this point the model in Blender looks like this:

[image: Object as it appears in Blender]

But after importing in After Effects and loading into Element 3D, it looks like this:

[image: Object as it appears in AE Element 3D]

I've tried doing the cell fracture a few different ways such as using own verts, own particles and both but nothing seems to make a difference.  If it helps, I am using Blender 2.71 and After Effects CS5.

Comment: Export it as `.obj` - this should work immediately.